# how to give array elements names from a column of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, names

I have array and df  below:

```
my.df <-  data.frame(cbind(c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6","a7","a8","a9","a10"), c(1:10)))
arr <- array(0, dim = c(2,3,10))
```

I want each element in my array gets its name from the corresponding row of my df.
meaning for example, first element of array must be names a1, senod must be named a2 and so one.

```
    for( i in q:nrow(my.df)){
dimnames(arr[,,i])[[3]] <- my.df[i,1]
   

 }
```

this is what I m trying to do, which is not working. how can I get to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original dataset the `dimnames` attribute is `NULL`.  So, we can create one with `list` specifying the first and second dimension names as `NULL` and the third from the first column of 'my.df'

```
dimnames(arr) <- list(NULL, NULL, my.df[[1]])
```

-output

```
> arr
, , a1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

, , a2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

, , a3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

, , a4

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

, , a5

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

, , a6

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

, , a7

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

, , a8

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

, , a9

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0

, , a10

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
```